# Firebase - cloud firestore - unit testing fails with error - TypeError: The "path" argument must be of type string

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs

Firebase - cloud firestore - unit testing fails with error 
- TypeError: The "path" argument must be of type string.

Otherwise, it works fine when run with NodeJS command 'node index.js'
I use service account and NodeJS

**myservice.js**

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./sakey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com"
});

const db = admin.firestore();


const getData = async () => {
    const snapshot = await db.collection('users').get()
    return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
}

module.exports = { getData }
```

**Test Case**

```
const { getData } = require('./myservice')

describe('my test suite', () => {

    it('Retrieve data', async () => {
        let result = await getData();
        return result().then(data => expect(data).toBeDefined())
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type objectTypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object

      at GrpcClient.loadProto (node_modules/google-gax/src/grpc.ts:166:23)
      at new FirestoreClient (node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_client.js:113:38)
      at ClientPool.clientFactory (node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:329:26)
      at ClientPool.acquire (node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/pool.js:87:35)
      at ClientPool.run (node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/pool.js:164:29)
      at node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:957:30
      at Firestore._retry (node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:822:38)
```

**package.json**

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
    "jest": "^25.1.0"
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/793#issuecomment-592334797):

> Adding a jest.config.js with the following code solved my issue
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>     testPathIgnorePatterns: ['lib/', 'node_modules/'],
>     moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
>     testEnvironment: 'node'
> };
> ```